# Is it "Had" or "Have"?

Tags: past-tense, past-participles, past-perfect

By 2005, ninety countries "had" joined the union. Is it had or have?

Comment: Would the same rules apply to this sentence: By October 2017, forty schools have adopted the system.

Comment: The usual choice would be 'had'. In conjunction with the 'historic present', you can meet structures such as 'In 1322, the famine deepens; many families have already deserted the plateau.'

Answer (score 2):

Since 2005 is a past time and you are considering an event(countries' joining of the union) that happened before 2005, "had" will be the correct choice.

For some further information, you can have a look at this article: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/past-perfect/

Comment: what if the event is current/ongoing? As in, By October 2017, forty schools have adopted the system.

Comment: Yes. If you are speaking of the current situation, it's 'have'.

Comment: I'm not going to accept answers to questions dealt with in Junior School, correct or otherwise.